# how do you test the "goodness-of-fit" for percentages? 2x3, Expected = 0 for some

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I have 3 test conditions.

Condition 1: samples expected to have have 100% of product A and 0% of B and C

Condition 2: 50% A and 50%B and 0%C

Condition 3: 33.3% of each A,B and C

I can use a Chi-square test for condition 2 and 3 since I won't have to divide by 0 (if i ignore C in condition 2), but I'm wondering if there's a way to calculate all conditions the same way.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation? Can you paste in example data?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a chi-square test for condition 1 because condition 1 follows a constant distribution, the random variable is not really random because it is constant.

If your null hypothesis predicts 100% of product A then when you collect data you have two possible outcomes:

- All samples are product A, the p-value is $1.0$
- One or more sample is not product A, the p-value is $0.0$

Your hypothesis is either obviously wrong or it perfectly predicts the samples observed, there is nothing between these extremes where you can have $p=0.05$ and say "the data is unlikely given the hypothesis"

Comment: I'm sure someone will feel the need to point out what I said about the constant distribution. I'm just making a point about the constant distribution, I'm not saying that it doesn't satisfy the formal definition of a random variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use: Bayesian Models Comparison based on Bayes Factor.

In this case, you have the relative probability between the various models; below I provide an R implementation.

Also, I found an article that uses Bayes Factor for a problem similar to your:

[The Bayes Factor Against Equiprobability of a Multinomial Population Assuming a Symmetric Dirichlet Prior][1]

The R language code is

```
library(stats)

p1 <-c(1,0,0)
p2<- c(0.5,0.5,0)
p3 <- c(1/3,1/3,1/3)
```

Generate a sample from p2

```
n.observations <-100

results<-rmultinom(1, size=n.observations, prob=p2)
prob_data_given_p1 <- dmultinom(results, prob = p1)
prob_data_given_p2 <- dmultinom(results, prob = p2)
prob_data_given_p3 <- dmultinom(results, prob = p3)
```

Here we define prior probabilities and assign same probability to the three models

```
prior_p1 <- 1/3
prior_p2 <- 1/3
prior_p3 <- 1/3
```

Calculate posteriors

```
prob_p1_given_data <- prob_data_given_p1* prior_p1
prob_p2_given_data <- prob_data_given_p2* prior_p2
prob_p3_given_data <- prob_data_given_p3* prior_p3
```

Calculate relative probabilities

```
p2_relative_to_p1 <-prob_p2_given_data/prob_p1_given_data
p2_relative_to_p3 <-prob_p2_given_data/prob_p3_given_data
print(p2_relative_to_p1)
print(p2_relative_to_p3)
```

Comment: its missing a link?